# Optimal way for creating and managing calculations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am developing a finance app, which has a `:transactions` table with some `key:values`. I am planning to create lots of categories for these transactions in the future and using all kinds of formulas and methods, including native sum, average, min, max, etc. I want to optimize my code in order not to break it when these categories are added. What is the optimal way to manage such calculations and data movement? I would like my formulas to update in real time quickly after a new transaction is submitted. For example, I need to create a TOTAL for my transactions. I learned that fat controllers are a bad practice, so my guess is to avoid going with

```
@transactions_total = Transaction.sum("amount_cents")
```

Should I create helpers or maybe go with a separate model? I am using the `money_rails` gem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails - moving out calculations from my views?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20002550/rails-moving-out-calculations-from-my-views)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A great solution to my question is given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20002550/rails-moving-out-calculations-from-my-views), therefore there is no need to keep this one open